# React componentDidUpdate lifecycle enters with null prevState

Tags: reactjs

React 16.13.1

Newbie.

I add the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method to my component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    //this.state
}

render () { ... }
```

In an onChange handler I update the state and `componentDidUpdate` fires. However `prevState` enters as null.  Also, within the method `this.state` is null.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you upadte your state as?
what is your initial state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Init the state first

Use `constructor()`, define the state data structure inside, as well as setting the init value of it.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component<Props, State>{
  static defaultProps = {
    classes: {},
  };
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`prevState` points to the state before the update (props or state changed), so its expected to be null in your case. You can initialize the state if you want:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {} // initialize here

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate');
        //this.state
    }

    render() { ... }
}
```